# Necesito ayuda con un pequeño script de PHP para mi acortador de URLs

Tags: php

Actualmente estoy creando un acortador de URLs programado en HTML, JavaScript, CSS y PHP. sin embargo, quiero limitarlo para que solamente se puedan acortar páginas específicas. En mi caso, me gustaría que se pudieran acortar solo 8 páginas.

**¿Qué es lo que necesito?**

Después de enviar el formulario de creación de una nueva URL acortada, necesito que PHP revise si el sitio web que desea acortar es alguno de los siguientes:

- minecraftpocket-servers.com
- minecraftpeservers.org

He oído que la URI corresponde a lo que sigue de un dominio (/...), y me gustaría que PHP se enfoque en limitar que el input del usuario (definido como $longlink) empieze con alguna de las ya mencionadas páginas (aunque voy a hacerlo para 8).

Intenté usar **array()**, pero me pide que el input del usuario sea exactamente el mismo, y quiero que el input del usuario pueda contener, por ejemplo https://minecraftpocket-servers.com/server/9/ y que sea válido (que tome en cuenta HTTP y HTTPS, o en realidad da lo mismo).

Eso sí, necesito que el código en sus respuestas incluya **else** para que me permita definir que sucederá cuando está bien y cuando está mal (ya que me confude un poco usar **else**).

Gracias por sus respuestas.

**Edición:**

Estoy utilizando el siguiente código para eliminar las extensiones .html sin ocasionar redireccionamientos infinitos:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.html [L]
```

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. [edit] tu pregunta agregando el código que hayas hecho para solucionar tu problema, descripción de los errores que tengas, etc.

Comment: Kevin, te ha valido la respuesta. Algún feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Yo no utilizaría el `.htaccess` de Apache.

En PHP, mete en un array los dominios válidos:

```
$dominios = ['minecraftpocket-servers.com', 'minecraftpeservers.org', ...];
```

Luego comprueba que la URL que se quiere acortar cumple todos los requisitos:

```
$url_parseada = parse_url($url);
if ( $url_parseada === false ) {
    die('URL incorrecta.');
} else if ( !isset($url_parseada['scheme']) || 
            ( $url_parseada['scheme'] != 'http' &&
              $url_parseada['scheme'] != 'https' ) ) {
    die('Protocolo de URL incorrecto.');
} else if ( isset($url_parseada['port']) &&
            $url_parseada['port'] != 80 &&
            $url_parseada['port'] != 443 ) {
    die('Puerto de URL incorrecto.');
} else if ( !in_array($url_parseada['host'], $dominios) ) {
    die('Dominio no permitido.');
}
```

Y ahora ya puedes acortar la URL y continuar.